# Sending pdf attachment with form using mail() function

Tags: php, html, email-attachments

I am trying to send pdf attachment with php `mail()` function. But i am not getting how i can do it. Message field in the form is user editable with html editor. Without attachment It works fine.

Here is my code

```
<?php
include("../connect.php"); 
include("../admin_auth.php"); ?>


<?php
if($_POST['submit'] == "Submit")
{

$sql = mysql_query("select email from users where username='admin'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$email = $row['email'];
$path = $row['path'];

    $messageAlert = "Email send successfully!!";

    $to   = $_POST['email'];
    $from = $email;


    $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
    if($_POST['type'] == 2)
    {
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    }

    mail($to, $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'], $headers);
}
$message .= "";
$content =$messageAlert.'<br>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Subject:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Message:</td>
        <td>

        <div class="w-box" id="n_wysiwg">
                            <div class="w-box-header">
                                <h4>WYSIWG Editor</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="w-box-content cnt_no_pad">
                                <textarea name="message" id="wysiwg_editor" cols="30" rows="10">'.$message.'</textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
       </td>

    </tr>
    <tr><td>Attachment</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="attachment" value="netelity.png"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email Type</td>
        <td><select name="type">
        <option value="1">Plain</option>
        <option value="2">HTML</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
';


$pre = 1;

include("html.inc");
```

Attachment will be in `$path` . I tried to follow [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132068/sending-multiple-attachment-files-in-php-mail-function) link, but as it uses `$message` as static, in my code it has to be from user input i.e `$_POST['message']`, it did not work.

Actually when i open this form i want the attachment to be attached itself.